# Common elements of two numpy ndarrays

Tags: python, tuples, numpy-ndarray

I have a `numpy` `ndarray` named `arr` with shape (200,) and a tuple `tup` containing another `ndarray` with shape (ndarray(150,)). I want to create a new array containing only the elements common to both `ndarray`s.

Comment: Tuples don't have a `shape` attribute. Both of those are numpy arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?  If the element is already in `arr`, what are you going to be adding?

Comment: @TimRoberts I want to add only what matches between those arrays

Comment: That says that the variable `tup` contains a numpy ndarray. Naming the variable `tup` doesn't make it a tuple.

Comment: Does [`numpy.intersect1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the `ndarray` out of the tuple and then compare:

```
arr2 = tup[0]
combined_arr = []

for i in arr:
  if i in arr2: combined_arr.append(i)
```

or with a list comprehension:

```
arr2 = tup[0]
combined_arr = [i for i in arr if i in arr2]
```

or `numpy` style with `intersect1d()` as @Barmar pointed out:

```
import numpy as np

...

arr2 = tup[0]
combined_arr = np.intersect1d(arr, arr2)
```

Comment: Edited the answer according to comment.

Comment: That as @Barmar says is a numpy multidimensional array a.k.a `ndarray`. (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)

Comment: Oh, `tup` is definitely a tuple. It is a tuple containing a single element and this element happens to be an `ndarray`.

Comment: any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: I have edited my answer. It now shows how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```py
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
tup = (32,5,4,6,90,45)

combined_arr = []
for i in arr:
    for t in tup:
        if i == t:
            #do this..
            #combine them into one arry 
            combined_arr.append(i)


print(combined_arr) # gives [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the most pythonic way would be using zip, to first zip the two sequences. This avoids any out of range errors.
For example with a list comprehension this looks like that:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 60, 7]
tup = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 7, 80, 90)
[arr_elem for arr_elem, tup_elem in (zip(arr, tup)) if arr_elem == tup_elem]
```

which will output the list

```
[60, 7]
```